# Reusable generic base class DAOs with Android Room

Tags: android, android-room, android-architecture-components

Is there any way to create reusable generic base class DAOs with Android Room?

```
public interface BaseDao<T> {

  @Insert
  void insert(T object);

  @Update
  void update(T object);

  @Query("SELECT * FROM #{T} WHERE id = :id")
  void findAll(int id);

  @Delete
  void delete(T object);

}

public interface FooDao extends BaseDao<FooObject> { ... }

public interface BarDao extends BaseDao<BarEntity> { ... }
```

I haven't been able to figure out any way of achieving this without having to declare the same interface members and write the query for each sub class. When dealing with a large number of similar DAOs this becomes very tedious...

Comment: The `insert()`, `update()`, and `delete()` methods should work as-is as I understand it -- Yigit wrote in an issue that this should be supported now. `findAll()` would have to be rewritten, to supply the table name.

Comment: Cool. I just found the issue. Looks like generic return/argument types will be supported from alpha3: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62103620

Comment: @CommonsWare Is it really possible to rewrite findAll? If so, how would it be done? I thought the table name needs to be known at compile time.

Comment: @MichaelUpdike: That's what I meant, replacing `#{T}` with `ThisIsTheTableName`. The net effect would be that `findAll()` would have to be pushed down the hierarchy to some class tied to a specific entity/table.

Answer (score 14):

Today, August 08, 2017, with version **1.0.0-alpha8** the Dao below works. I can have other Dao heroing the GenericDao.

```
@Dao
public interface GenericDao<T> {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    void insert(T... entity);

    @Update
    void update(T entity);

    @Delete
    void delete(T entity);
}
```

However, GenericDao can not be included in my Database class

Comment: This appears to be about a problem you have and does not seem to be an answer to the original question. If so, please delete and ask a brand new question of your own.

Comment: That's exactly the solution, most likely the reason it does not work for some people is the version used.

Comment: Your answer does not say what you just said in your comment, and the answer is very difficult to decipher at that.

Answer (score 7):

Generic findAll function:

base repository and dao:

```
abstract class BaseRepository<T>(private val entityClass: Class<T>) {

    abstract val dao: BaseDao<T>

    fun findAll(): List<T> {
        return dao.findAll(SimpleSQLiteQuery("SELECT * FROM ${DatabaseService.getTableName(entityClass)}"))
    }
}

interface BaseDao<T> {

    @RawQuery
    fun findAll(query: SupportSQLiteQuery): List<T>
}
```

database service:

```
object DatabaseService {

    fun getEntityClass(tableName: String): Class<*>? {
        return when (tableName) {
            "SomeTableThatDoesntMatchClassName" -> MyClass::class.java
            else -> Class.forName(tableName)
        }
    }

    fun getTableName(entityClass: Class<*>): String? {
        return when (entityClass) {
            MyClass::class.java -> "SomeTableThatDoesntMatchClassName"
            else -> entityClass.simpleName
        }
    }
}
```

example repo and dao:

```
class UserRepository : BaseRepository<User>(User::class.java) {

    override val dao: UserDao
        get() = database.userDao

}

@Dao
interface UserDao : BaseDao<User>
```

Comment: This is the perfect and complete solution

Comment: Can you please provide me the example link of this code?

Answer (score 5):

I have a solution for findAll.

Codes in that BaseDao:

```
...
public List<T> findAll() {
    SimpleSQLiteQuery query = new SimpleSQLiteQuery(
        "select * from " + getTableName()
    );
    return doFindAll(query);
}
...
public String getTableName() {
    // Below is based on your inheritance chain
    Class clazz = (Class)
        ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getSuperclass().getGenericSuperclass())
            .getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    // tableName = StringUtil.toSnakeCase(clazz.getSimpleName());
    String tableName = clazz.getSimpleName();
    return tableName;
}
...
@RawQuery
protected abstract List<T> doFindAll(SupportSQLiteQuery query);
```

and other Dao looks like :

```
@Dao
public abstract class UserDao extends AppDao<User> {
}
```

That's all

The idea is

1. Get the table name of subclass's generic type on runtime
2. Pass that table name to a RawQuery

If you prefer interface to abstract class, you can try optional method of java 8.

It's not beautiful but worked, as you can see.

[I created a gist at here](https://gist.github.com/clxy/5e51e9eb000ca07b7a7adb6bde767ff0)

Comment: This does work nicely for the given case but won't provide observables for LiveData.  Thanks, still helps my BaseDao class!

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you can do it only for `insert()`, `update()`, and `delete()`, as it doesn't require specific SQL statement that needs to be verified at compile time.

example:

BaseDao.java

```
public interface BaseDao<T> {

    @Insert
    void insert(T obj);

    @Insert
    void insert(T... obj);

    @Update
    void update(T obj);

    @Delete
    void delete(T obj);
}
```

UserDao.java

```
@Dao
abstract class UserDao implements BaseDao<User> {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM User")
    abstract List<User> getUser();

}
```

[source](https://medium.com/google-developers/7-pro-tips-for-room-fbadea4bfbd1)

Answer (score 1):

It should be implemented as following:

```
interface BaseDao<T : BaseEntity> {
    @Insert
    fun insert(entity: T)

    @Insert
    fun insert(vararg entities: T)

    @Update
    fun update(entity: T)

    @Delete
    fun delete(entity: T)

    fun getAll(): LiveData<List<T>>
}



@Dao
abstract class MotorDao : BaseDao<Motor> {

    @Query("select * from Motor")
    abstract override fun getAll(): LiveData<List<Motor>>

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I agree with your thinking, the answer is no. For several reasons.

1. When the `fooDao_Impl.java` is generated from your `@Dao fooDao extends BaseDao<Foo>` class, you will be met with a lot of "cannot find class Symbol T" errors. This is due to the method Room uses to generate dao implementations. This is a method that will not support your desired outcome, and is unlikely to change soon (in my opinion, due to type erasure).
2. Even if this is resolved, Room does not support dynamic `@Dao` queries, in an effort to prevent SQL injection. This means you can only dynamically insert values into queries, not column names, table names, or query commands. In the example you have you could not use `#{T}` as it would breach this principle. In theory if the problem detailed in point 1 is resolved you could user insert, delete and update though.