# Android Room: storing an object hierarchy and querying for the superclass

Tags: android, polymorphism, android-room

In my application there is a User superclass and Coach and Player classes that extend User.
I'd like to be able to use DAO methods like these:

```
@Query
fun getUsers(): Flowable<List<User>>
```

and not have to request Coaches and Players separatly.
When I try something like this now my generated implementation class is not valid because it tries to create User objects, which is an abstract class.

Is there a way for Room to attain this polymorphic behaviour? Should the User class also have an @Entity tag or not? The User has the UUID that is being used as a Primary key.

Comment: https://commonsware.com/AndroidArch/previews/polymorphic-room-relations

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46317047/does-room-support-entity-inheritance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44746225/reusable-generic-base-class-daos-with-android-room#answer-45578682

Comment: Just google it...